# IntelliJ IDEA: default parameter values in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, default-value, invariance

In Scala REPL I can use `Seq[String]()` as a default value for a parameter of type `Seq[T]`.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def d[T](foo: Seq[T] = Seq[String]()) = 12
d: [T](foo: Seq[T])Int

scala> d()
res0: Int = 12
```

Trying the same in IDEA, it complains “Seq[String] doesn't conform to expected type Seq[T]”. **Why?**

[image: Screenshot of IDEA complaining about a type problem for parameter default values]

- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
- Scala Plugin 2016.2.1
- Scala 2.11.7

Note 1: Sorry, I know that my example function does not make much sense. However, my real (and useful) function is unnecessarily complex to post it here.

Note 2: At first, instead of type **T** my type name in the example was **Any** which was not a good idea (because it shadowed scala.Any) and caused some confusion. Thus I fixed that.

Comment: I tried the same code in eclipse with same scala version. To my surprise, i'm not getting any error

Comment: Strangely enough, If I copy-paste your piece of code in IntelliJ, i have the same red underlined text. But the compilation process is just fine. I guess it's a bug in IntelliJ Scala plugin, that's it.

Comment: It is indeed a bug in IntelliJ Scala plugin type conformance. I've created an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `def d[Any]`, the `Any` here is a generic place holder. It does not point to class `Any` in scala. It basically shadows the `Any` class defined globally in scala. So, when you assign `Seq[String]` to Seq`[Any]`, the compiler does not know any relation between `String` and `Any`. Note that `Any` could be replaced with any character / word as generic place holder. The result would be the same.

Now coming, to why this works in REPL, I am not exactly sure why REPL accepts if `Seq[String]` when given as a default value, but I was able to reproduce the error in repl when I do the same operation inside the method body.

The following code in REPL throws error:

```
def d[Any](foo: Seq[Any]) = {
  val a: Seq[Any] = Seq[String]()
}
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
found   : Seq[String]
required: Seq[Any]
       val a: Seq[Any] = Seq[String]()
                                    ^
```

I am not sure why REPL was not able to catch the error while given as a default argument.

One alternative theory is, in general when you use generics, the value of the type will be determined based on the caller. For example,

```
def d[A](a:A) = {}
d(1) // Type of A is Int
d("a") // Type of A is String
```

So, when you give default value, it assigns the value of `String` to `Any`. hence the compilation success.Intellij's Type Checker works based on the first theory and shows an error. But strangely as someone pointed out earlier, the compilation succeeds.

Comment: @BalajiReddy As I said, it might be how Intellij Idea's Type Checker works. Eclipse might have gotten it right. Also since both REPL & Scala IDE for eclipse are implemented by the developers of Scala, it seems to be the right approach. So this makes me conclude that the second theory I had mentioned is the exact answer.

Comment: `Seq` is covariant. Which means `Seq[+A]` can accept subclasses of `A` in the sequence. The doesnt mean `Seq[String]` matches `Seq[T]`. You cant confirm this unless  `T` is related to `String`. Even `List` is covariant. As far as I understand Intellij will show error even when you use `def d[T](foo: Seq[T] = Seq[String]()) = {  }`. But will compile successfully. I guess the answer is a bug with intellij's type checker. It would help you change your question to `def d[T](foo: Seq[T] = Seq[String]()) = {  }` to avoid confusion between the class `Any` defined in scala and the type parameter.

Comment: Though `Seq[String]()` matches `Seq[Any]`. But you are right. It's not scala.Any in my def example. Thus I replaced Any by T.

Comment: So ultimately it’ simply a bug in IDEA Scala Plugin. Thanks for helping me to understand (and improve) my code :)

Comment: I am not confirming it is a bug in Idea. Its better to raise a bug in their bug tracker. But based on the behaviour, it seems so.